Unable to find Chromium that works with Chrome
My chrome is version Version 127.0.6533.89 64-bit. I downloaded the according chromedriver from [https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/#stable][1], which is version 127.0.6533.88 (mine is .89).
When I run my program I get the following errors:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Kovy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 95, in start
    path = SeleniumManager().driver_location(browser)
  File "C:\Users\Kovy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\selenium_manager.py", line 74, in driver_location
    result = self.run((binary, flag, browser))
  File "C:\Users\Kovy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\selenium_manager.py", line 93, in run
    raise SeleniumManagerException(f"Selenium manager failed for: {command}.\n{stdout}{stderr}")
selenium.common.exceptions.SeleniumManagerException: Message: Selenium manager failed for: C:\Users\Kovy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\windows\selenium-manager.exe --browser chrome.
WARN    Error getting version of chromedriver 127. Retrying with chromedriver 126 (attempt 1/5)
WARN    Error getting version of chromedriver 126. Retrying with chromedriver 125 (attempt 2/5)
WARN    Error getting version of chromedriver 125. Retrying with chromedriver 124 (attempt 3/5)
WARN    Error getting version of chromedriver 124. Retrying with chromedriver 123 (attempt 4/5)
WARN    Error getting version of chromedriver 123. Retrying with chromedriver 122 (attempt 5/5)
ERROR   The chromedriver version cannot be discovered


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Kovy\Desktop\Programs\teumim.py", line 62, in <module>
    first_name, last_name = get_webpage()
  File "c:\Users\Kovy\Desktop\Programs\teumim.py", line 19, in get_webpage
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)
  File "C:\Users\Kovy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 80, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "C:\Users\Kovy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 101, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Users\Kovy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 98, in start   
    raise err
  File "C:\Users\Kovy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 88, in start   
    self._start_process(self.path)
  File "C:\Users\Kovy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 209, in _start_process
    raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/home

Regarding the 2nd question, I added the file that chromedriver.exe is in to the PATH, and its still giving me the error. And regarding the first problem, I have the most updated version - how is it too old?
Here is the code:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

def get_webpage():
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
    chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

    # Specify the path to chromedriver.exe
    chromedriver_path = 'C:/Users/Kovy/Download/chromedriver-win64/chromedriver-win64/chromedriver.exe'
    service = Service(executable_path=chromedriver_path)

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)

    try:
        email = "email"
        password = "code"

        url = 'https://accounts.google.com/'
        driver.get(url)
        time.sleep(15)  # Wait for the page to load

        input_username = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'identifier')
        input_username.send_keys(email)
        input_username.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

        time.sleep(2)

        input_password = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'Passwd')
        input_password.send_keys(password)
        input_password.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

        time.sleep(25)  # Wait for login to complete

        webpage_content = driver.page_source

    finally:
        driver.quit()

    # Parse the HTML with BeautifulSoup
    soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage_content, 'html.parser')

    # Find all <p> tags and extract their text
    paragraphs = soup.find_all('p')
    text_content = '\n'.join([p.get_text() for p in paragraphs])

    # Dummy values for first_name and last_name
    first_name = "a"
    last_name = "b"
    return first_name, last_name

def download(first_name, last_name):
    print(f"First Name: {first_name}, Last Name: {last_name}")

while True:
    first_name, last_name = get_webpage()
    download(first_name, last_name)
    time.sleep(60)  # Delay between iterations


for some reason the built-in drivermanager is trying to read the driver version and is failing.  (I'd have thought the drivermanager would not run when setting the path manually... maybe also set browser binary path using chrome options.)

Try to leave "service" away and just don't use an executable path.
